# Can I set SetsRequiredMembers or another attribute for only one member in C# 11?

Tags: c#, c#-11.0

Consider the following code:

```cs
public record Foo 
{
  public required string A { get; init; }
  public required string B { get; init; }
}

public record Bar : Foo
{
   public Bar()
   {
     A = "TEST";
   }
}

var bar = new Bar
{
  B = "ANOTHER TEST"
}
```

In this situation the compiler will say that field `A` is not set, while it is clearly set it just does not know about it. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Don't use such constructors? `required` says that the *client* must initialize the field or parameter. NRTs already generated a warning/error if the parameters weren't initialized

Comment: Why not? It makes sense that I always want this field initialized, but a subclass already has done it so that we need to write a bit less code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, at the moment there is no way to set it for a specific member. If `Foo` is external dependency you can workaround by adding ctor parameter for `B` and using `SetsRequiredMembersAttribute`:

```cs
public record Bar : Foo
{
   [SetsRequiredMembers]
   public Bar(string b)
   {
     A = "TEST";
     B = b;      
   }
}

var bar = new Bar("");
```

But use it with caution - it does not actually check if the ctor does what it claims to, i.e. adding new required member to `Foo` will not trigger an error.

[Demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQBECWAhgOYB2A9gM4Au+AxpdgMLnACmAgqYQDYCelfJQDcyKAGZMMdE3QBvZOiWZJUACzoAsgAoAlPMXKjAN0IAndACNz6ALzpSbAO7oAQue0AiT7tFIjAL7IQUhikmZsdORmwOgAYuTk6MgK/iroEQCOAK74EbFYGBzy6MRs1MLo+KT4FeghShIZbDl5bAVwGK4lZXXVtZUN6AD0w+lZufmYnTI95ZX9dQHoALTo2aRRALZbbKS0pMToTvg8PA7k1M2U2TxX1ehsZmbRwchhzVExbjYg8YkpQzoADaAGVypQAEotSbtTRsLaWJ6UAC6QKa7jM2kKVl0QNSRnQxXsngAKgBRUGkzx+QndeyWSqEoEhELIIA===)

Created an [API proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/65358) for attribute allowing to specify initialized members.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer, but a workaround that seems to work fine:

```cs
public record Foo(string A)
{
  public required string B { get; init; }
}

public record Bar : Foo("TEST")
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can set required only one member if needed.

```
public record Foo
{
    public string A { get; init; }
    public required string B { get; init; }
}
public record Bar : Foo
{
    public Bar() 
    {
        A = "TEST";
    }
}
var bar = new Bar
      {
         B = "ANOTHER TEST"
      };
```

Comment: This is not quite what I wanted to achieve, I still want it required, but I do want the compiler to understand that it is already set by the constructor