# How can I use a common initializer for init properties in a base class?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, .net-7.0, c#-11.0

Consider the following classes in C# 11:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public required string BaseProperty { get; init; }
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public required string ChildProperty { get; init; }
}
```

The standard way to initialize the derived class is:

```
var a = new ChildClass
{
    BaseProperty = "abc",
    ChildProperty = "def"
};
```

This works fine but becomes tedious if the base class has a lot of properties or there are many derived classes. Is there any way to use a common, centralized initializer for the base class such that only the additional properties need to be initialized for derived classes? Something like (invented syntax follows):

```
void Main()
{       
    var a = new ChildClass : BaseInitializer()
    {
        ChildProperty = "def"
    };
}

BaseClass BaseInitializer()
{
    return new BaseClass
    {
        BaseProperty = "abc"
    };
}
```

Without this functionality it seems that the `required` and `init` keywords are only useful for basic scenarios not involving inheritance.

My question is a bit similar to [Can I set SetsRequiredMembers or another attribute for only one member in C# 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74400456/can-i-set-setsrequiredmembers-or-another-attribute-for-only-one-member-in-c-shar), except that question is asking how to apply a broad attribute to only one property, while I am wondering how to use two different initializers on the same instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I set SetsRequiredMembers or another attribute for only one member in C# 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74400456/can-i-set-setsrequiredmembers-or-another-attribute-for-only-one-member-in-c-shar). See also [this proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/6536) (and related ones).

Comment: This seems similar to the first point I mentioned in [my answer about the downsides of `required`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74583049/5133585) here. It is apparently [by design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/required-members#override-rules) that overridden properties cannot make the property less required.

Comment: What's the use-case here? Perhaps a tool like [Automapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html) can solve the problem for you.

Comment: @Xerillio The use-case is as I described it in the question -- centralizing the initialization logic when a complicated base class has many properties, or is inherited by many different derived classes. In these cases we don't want to replicate a lot of common initialization code if we can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to go for this is with constructors:

```
var a = new ChildClass(
    BaseInitializer(), 
    childProperty: "xxx");


record BaseClass
{
    public required string BaseProperty { get; init; }
}

record ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    [SetsRequiredMembers]
    public ChildClass(BaseClass original, string childProperty) : base(original)
    {
        ChildProperty = childProperty;
    }

    public required string ChildProperty { get; init; }
}
```

---

Please note that [Required Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/required-members) C# 11 feature specification says:

> In versions of this proposal with the init clause, we talked about being able to have the following scenario:
>
> ```
> public class Base
> {
>    protected required int _field;
>
>     protected Base() {} // Contract required that _field is set
> }
> public class Derived : Base
> {
>     public Derived() : init(_field = 1) // Contract is fulfilled and _field is removed from the required members list
>     {
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> However, we have removed the init clause from the proposal at this point, so we need to decide whether to allow this scenario in a limited fashion. The options we have are:
> (...)